# creating index with elasticsearch river

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to poll the data from database table - User and populate in elasticsearch, I specify the index name in the "index" section giving a name, the index is being created as "jdbc". Thus I can only query it as "host/jdbc/_search  what is this about ?

This is the POST request for creating users index

```
http://localhost:9200/_river/users/_meta

{
"type" :
 "jdbc",

 "schedule" : "0 0-59 0-23 ? * *",

 "jdbc" : 
  {

    "driver":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",

    "url" : "jdbc:mysql://192.168.52.202/test_dev",

    "user" : "test_user",

    "password" : "test_pass", 

    "sql" : "select id as _id,first_name,city,email from USERS",

    "index":"users",

    "type":"user"

   }

}
```

[image: elasticsearch-plugin-head]

[image]

[image: user type]
Thank you in  advance :)

Comment: You'll have to specify the index name and type within the river json e.g "index":"user", "type":"student". I'm not sure I understand the rest of the question thought!

Comment: I did that -  check json structure

Comment: after this post request I got my user data under jdbc index so I can search for user only with host/jdbc/_search . (the second picture)

Comment: Sorry my bad. I didn't pay attention to the those line. Try to create your river using the PUT method.

Comment: Tnx for help but I already did that , I got the same structure.User is created as type under river. I added new picture

Comment: When I moved  index and index type in separate block I got _river and users index:)

Comment: Cool! You can write a details answer now and accept it.

Comment: http://localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta - post                                
{
"type" :
 "jdbc",

 "schedule" : "0 0-59 0-23 ? * *",

 "jdbc" : 
  {
    "strategy":"simple",

    "driver":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",

    "url" : "jdbc:mysql://192.168.52.202/test_dev",

    "user" : "test",

    "password" : "test_pass", 

    "sql" : "select id as _id,first_name,city,email from USERS",

     "poll":"2s"

   },
 "index": {
        "index":"users",
        "type":"user",
        "bulk_size":500
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I added index and type in the jdbc block. I saw that in few example.After I changed the json structure , I  moved index and type in the index block I got river and users index

localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta - post

{
"type" :
 "jdbc",

"schedule" : "0 0-59 0-23 ? * *",

"jdbc" : 
  {
    "strategy":"simple",

```
"driver":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",

"url" : "jdbc:mysql://192.168.52.202/test_dev",

"user" : "test",

"password" : "test_pass", 

"sql" : "select id as _id,first_name,city,email from USERS",

 "poll":"2s"
```

},
 "index": {
        "index":"users",
        "type":"user",
        "bulk_size":500
    }
}